# xDebugger not binding to port I believe

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I am trying to get phpstorm debugging with my local virtual server with x.debug (ubuntu 12.1) but not having any luck.

First I have made sure no ports are in use on both the mac and the virtual machine ie,

```
# vm
root@ubuntu:~# lsof  | grep "9000"
root@ubuntu:~# 

#mac
oes$ sudo lsof -i TCP:9000
Password:
oes$
```

So to test the php can bind to the port I have tried with this simple script loaded on the the vm.

```
<?php
$address = '192.168.1.90';  << my MAC's ip
$port = 9001;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
```

Im just getting error:  Unable to bind

Looking at the iptables in the vm I can see its all open.

```
root@ubuntu:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

On the Mac I have turned Firewall off.

Install xdebug was painless but for now have disabled it to check the ports.

Really hope someone can advise.

Comment: xdebug is the one that connects to IDE, not other way around. You need to make sure that xdebug port (TCP 9000, by default) is allowed in firewall on your Mac (or, in other words, PhpStorm is allowed to receive connections on that port) and that PhpStorm listens on that port (after using Debug button on correct Run/DEbug configuration .. or by using "phone handle" icon).

Comment: Useful link (can be) to read about how it works: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Yes LazyOne, the script is on the virtual machine. So it should connect to the mac port. But its not!

Comment: 1) In this case enable logging and see what it does (if IP:port is correct; if it tires to connect at all etc): http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log (restarting Apache most likely required) 2) Is PhpStorm actually listening on xdebug port?